# ClassLoader Resource not found from UnitTest

Tags: java

I have a class method that reads resource file, but file can not be find when I'm trying to run this class with unit tests.

If I were to deploy application war or just run it from eclipse using maven, everything works just fine.

File locations (not sure if src/test/resources is needed, added it only after I encountered the problem, did not help though):

```
src/main/resources/
    -> com
        -> xxxx
            -> xxxx_portal
                -> web
                    -> server
                        -> servlet
                            -> reports -> Logo.png
src/test/resources/
    -> com
        -> xxxx
            -> xxxx_portal
                -> web
                    -> server
                        -> servlet
                            -> reports -> Logo.png
```

Relevant class code:

```
package com.xxxx.xxxx_portal.web.server.servlet.reports;

public class ModuleReports {
    private static final String LOGO_IMAGE_PATH = "/com/xxxx/xxxx_portal/web/server/servlet/reports/Logo.png";

    ...
    private static InputStream getLogoImage() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(LOGO_IMAGE_PATH); //Problem here, InputStream is null. It should not be null.
        return is;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream must not start with a slash (`/`).  While you could just remove the initial slash from the value of ACDLABS_LOGO_IMAGE_PATH, you should use Class.getResourceAsStream rather than ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream:

```
private static InputStream getLogoImage() {
    return ModuleReports.class.getResourceAsStream("ACDLogo.png");
}
```

Unlike ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream, the argument to Class.getResourceAsStream *can* start with a slash, but doesn’t need to.  If it doesn’t, the string is assumed to point to a resource in the same package as the class on which it is invoked.  All of this behavior is described in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I was hoping not to touch this Class and its methods if possible. Are you saying that removing slash will make unit test work? Because as I stated, Class ModuleReports works fine with slash when not running from unit tests.

Comment: It’s worth trying.  You may also want to update your question and show how your application is built;  that is, show the Maven pom.xml or the Ant build.xml.

Comment: Removing slash works. Though this is a strange behavior, since deployed application works fine either way (with or without starting slash) while unit test works only if starting slash is removed.

Comment: The nature of an object-oriented API is that if you meet the conditions specified in the documentation, the method call is guaranteed to work.  If you don’t… it might or might not work, but the conditions under which it happens to work may change from release to release or from environment to environment.